# prefill text boxes with value from url parameters using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to grab the values from parameters in the url and use that to populate some textboxes on my page but i cant figure it out. can anyone help (p.s im new to angular)

This is my example texboxes

```
<div class="container">
    val1: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.txt1" />
    val2:<input type="text" ng-model="vm.txt2" />
</div>
```

here is the example code in my controller

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

     angular.module('app').controller('exampleController', ExampleController);

     ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$window', '$http', '$templateCache'];       

     function ExampleController($scope, $location, $window, $http,   $templateCache) {
         var location = $location;
         var url = $scope.location.url('http://www.example.com/examplepage?name=todd&age=20');
         $scope.vm.txt1 = $scope.location.search().name;
         $scope.vm.txt2 = $scope.location.search().age;
     };
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
   var location = $location;
   var url = $scope.location.url('http://www.example.com/examplepage?name=todd&age=20');
    $scope.vm.txt1 = $scope.location.search().name;
    $scope.vm.txt2 = $scope.location.search().age;
```

Should be:

```
  $scope.vm.txt1 = $scope.location.search().name;
  $scope.vm.txt2 = $scope.location.search().age;
```

You can remove the local "var location = $location" as $location will suffice. There is no need to add $location to your $scope for this instance.

Comment: Thanks so much this did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Controller

In the controller, just set:

```
$scope.urlParams = $location.search();
```

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="urlParams.name" />
<input type="text" ng-model="urlParams.age" />
```